# Need some advice with React connect()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to map a dispatch to props, but no matter what I try, it is not working.

The props doesn't contain the function that I am trying to pass.

Here is my code:

(/src/components/containers/CommentForm.js)

```
import CommentForm from '../ui/CommentForm';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addComment } from '../../actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  showModal: state.showModal,
  video: state.video
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onNewComment({ username, text }) {
    dispatch(addComment(username, text));
  }
});

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CommentForm);

export default withRouter(Container);
```

I have about the same code in another container which works fine. When I console.log(props) in the constructor in the imported '../ui/CommentForm' file, I get only the props set in the CommentForm tag:

```
<CommentForm video={video} showModal={this.state.commentsAllowed && this.state.showCommentForm} toggleCommentForm={this.toggleCommentForm} />
```

Function onNewComment is not there:

```
{video: {…}, showModal: false, toggleCommentForm: ƒ}
```

I have been going over this for several hours and have not been able to find a solution. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:**

(/src/components/ui/CommentForm.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";

export default class CommentForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this._username = React.createRef();
    this._text = React.createRef();

    this.state = props.video;

    console.log(props);
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    /**
     * New comment
     */
    this.props.video.comments.push({'username': event.target.username.value, 'text': event.target.text.value});
    this.setState({video: this.props.video});

    this.props.onNewComment({
      username: event.target.username.value,
      text: event.target.text.value
    });

    this.props.toggleCommentForm();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={this.props.showModal} centered>
        <form className="comment-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Modal.Header>
          <h5 className="modal-title">Comment Form</h5>
          <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.props.toggleCommentForm} data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <label className="row form-group">
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-4">Username:</div>
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-8"><input className="form-control" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Your Username" ref={input => (this._username = input)} required /></div>
          </label>
          <label className="row form-group">
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-4">Comments:</div>
            <div className="col-12 col-sm-8"><textarea className="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Your comments" ref={input => (this._text = input)} required /></div>
          </label>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </Modal.Footer>
        </form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

CommentForm.propTypes = {
  onNewComment: PropTypes.func
}
```

So, this.props.onNewComment is failing with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onNewComment is not a function
```

Comment: Where you're trying to use it are you importing the decorated component, or the original `CommentForm` component? Can you update your question with the code for the component where you are trying to use the form and log its props?

Comment: I have just updated my question.

Comment: I think somewhere you're importing the undecorated component, i.e. "/src/components/ui/CommentForm.js" instead of "/src/components/containers/CommentForm.js" . If you make `onNewComponent` a required prop in "/src/components/ui/CommentForm.js" it may help illuminate where it's not being passed: `onNewComment: PropTypes.func.isReuired`. It'll generate a react warning in the console.

Comment: I have found the mistake, I was indeed importing as follows: import CommentForm from './ui/CommentForm'; instead of import CommentForm from '../containers/CommentForm'; This was just a bad overlooked mistake that took hours.

Comment: If it's worth anything, it may help to *not* default export the undecorated component and move the HOCs into the component file being decorated (to be default exported, and/or not giving the decorated and undecorated components identical names.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code and you must have addNewComment method under Actions.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
            addNewComment: Actions.addNewComment
        },
        dispatch);
}
```

and import

```
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
```